# Error w pip install openbabel: Failed to build openbabel

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I've been asked by my professor to install openbabel on my Mac for a project, but am having problems with installation.

I'm doing

```
pip install openbabel
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Collecting openbabel
  Using cached openbabel-2.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: openbabel
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for openbabel ... error
```

[The error continues here](https://gist.github.com/MelanieS/5301a83051c04bb41edfa8c28949fe17).

My research advisor had me install anaconda to hopefully remedy my issues.
`which pip` yields  `/Users/melanie/anaconda/bin/pip`, so I think I'm good there.

Using Python 3.6.1

Any advice? Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your research adviser has already tell you the solution.

As you are using `Anaconda`, try `conda install -c openbabel openbabel`. Then you are done.