# importing openbabel wrapper pybel for macos without conda

Tags: python, macos, pip, openbabel, pybel

Previously I asked how to install openbabel for macos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639229/installing-openbabel-with-pip). Now I also need to install the openbabel python wrapper pybel. I tried `pip install pybel` and it was installed. Then, while I was following the tutorial,

```
import openbabel
import pybel
mymol = pybel.readstring("smi", "CCCC")
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pybel' has no attribute 'readstring'
```

It turns out other people had similar issues and in fact I found in the [mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/openbabel/mailman/message/35827645/) that, I quote

> 'I guess you installed pybel via `pip install pybel`, which is the
>   "wrong" pybel'

Then they give a solution which is `pip install openbabel`, which is not possible for macos.

[A solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851695/error-w-pip-install-openbabel-failed-to-build-openbabel) is to use `conda` to install openbabel but I am not using conda and I would like to keep it that way so I am looking for a solution which does not require `conda`.

Comment: if you followed the advice on compiling `openbabel` from source, the bindings should already be compiled, you should be able to do `from openbabel import pybel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, you can `brew install open-babel` and then give the path to homebrewed library of python site-packages. For me the following works:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

Then you can

```
import openbabel
from openbabel import pybel
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. It works with the following code:

```
from openbabel import pybel
mymol = pybel.readstring("smi","CCN(CC)CC")
mymol
```

Comment: Thanks but actually this also didn't work. Turns out I imported the wrong pybel...

Comment: you need to uninstall the wrong pybel first. I made the same mistake. `pip uninstall pybel`